# PHP Calculation from database not calculating correctly.

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a sum from numbers taken from a database. However i can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why i keep getting 0 instead of a percentage? if so could you guide me in the right direction.

PHP:

```
//SQL Original Goal
$goal = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$login'";
$goalquery = mysql_query($goal);
$goalarray = mysql_fetch_array($goalquery); 
$endgoal = $goalarray['goal'];

    //Latest Weight
$latestweightarray = mysql_fetch_array($latestweightq);
$currentweight = $latestweightarray['weight'];

    //First Weight Recorded
$firstweightarray = mysql_fetch_array($firstweightq);
$firstweight = $firstweightarray['weight'];

$percent = "100";

$progress = (($firstweight - $currentweight) / ($firstweight - $endgoal)) * $percent;
```

Print Result:

```
<?php 
echo $progress 
?>
```

This just gives: 0

Comment: where is this assigned? `$latestweightq` and `$firstweightq`

Comment: What are the values that make up the $progress formula? if any of the three sections are 0, the answer will be 0. - If $firstweight == $currentweight or $firstweight == $endgoal?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: `var_dump` all variables before calculation, make sure they are correct.

Comment: Check out mysql_connect. Pass the connection pointer in your mysql_query call.

Comment: endgoal = 85 
first weight = 102
current weight = 90

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rookie Error, i had updated the database twice in one day which conflicted the results somehow, changed one of the dates in the database and this solved the problem